# what has text-align got to do with image?

Tags: css

I was just reading this article :-

http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Please note this css :-

```
#bg td {
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

What is text-align doing in here? If i just remove that property, it stops working. CSS can be quiet difficult to understand sometimes :(

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The first of the two techniques listed on that page is quite terrible.  The second is alright.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Image elements are `inline-block` by default which basically means that things that normally apply only to text applies to images as well, but it also means that you can put e.g. padding and margin on the element, which you cannot put on elements that are normally "inline" such as `span`.

So what I'm trying to say is that since images are `inline-block`, the CSS property `text-align` applies to them.